# CRON не может записать данные в БД

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, cron

Переношу парсер с одного VDS на другой и столкнулся с проблемой. На прошлом ресурсе все работало как часы, а сейчас есть проблема с записью полей в БД mysql. То есть он может брать инфу с БД и выдавать ее. Через интерефейс он может даже записывать значения в базу данных, а вот уже через CRON такая фишка не прокатывает.
Помогите пожалуйста! Что делать? В какую сторону капать?
В самом скрипте уверен так как на прошлом сервере все работает!

Comment: по старинке - искать (включить) логи и смотреть в них. Если все равно будет недопонимание - бросать сюда (желательно не всю простыню), если ещё будет непонимание, показывать скрипт.

Comment: *через CRON такая фишка не прокатывает* Пардон, но "через CRON" можно только запустить выполнение некоей команды ОС. Что за команда должна "записывать значения в базу"? а заодно - а от имени какой учётной записи она это собирается делать?

Comment: Я имел ввиду что крон, запускает скрипт PHP, который уже должен запись выполнить. Я сижу под root. И скорее всего что она выполняется с максимальными правами. Хотя я не уверен. 
Логи ошибок mysql чистые. То есть ошибок и особых замечаний там нет вовсе

Comment: Вообще ничего не понять. Зачем в этой связке CRON? почему не записывать прямо из PHP? С чего Вы решили, что CRON выполняет задания под рутом? Задание в CRON вообще выполняется? А возникшие при его выполнении ошибки - фиксируются? Что попадает в General log (если включить, конечно)?